# NestJS schedualers are not working in production

Tags: deployment, cron, nestjs, backend, vercel

I have a BE service in NestJS that is deployed in Vercel.

I need several schedulers, so I have used @nestjs/schedule lib, which is super easy to use.

Locally, everything works perfectly.
For some reason, the only thing that is not working in my production environment is those schedulers. Everything else is working - endpoints, data base access..

Does anyone has an idea why? is it something with my deployment? maybe Vercel has some issue with that? maybe this schedule library requires something the Vercel doesn't have?

I am clueless..

Comment: If you are usig cold boot functions, that might not work with crons, which is what the schedule lib is built upon. When the cron runs, your machine might be offline. Or perhaps there is a way to keep your machine running and avoid cold boots, that could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what does cold boot functions means?

Answer (score 0):

Cold boot is the process of starting a computer from shutdown or a powerless state and setting it to normal working condition.

Which means that the code you deployed in a serveless manner, will run when the endpoint is called. The platform you are using spins up a virtual machine, to execute your code. And keeps the machine running for a certain period of time, incase you get another API hit, it's cheaper and easier on them to keep the machine running for lets say 5 minutes or 60 seconds, than to redeploy it on every call after shutting the machine when function execution ends.

So in your case, most likely what is happening is that the machine that you are setting the cron on, is killed after a period of time. Crons are system specific tasks which run in the kernel. But if the machine is shutdown, the cron dies with it. The only case where the cron would run, is if the cron was triggered at a point of time, before the machine was shut down.

Certain cloud providers give you the option to keep the machines alive. I remember google cloud used to follow the path of that if a serveless function is called frequently, it shifts from cold boot to hot start, which doesn't kill the machine entirely, and if you have traffic the machines stay alive.

From quick research, vercel isn't the best to handle crons, due to the nature of the infrastructure, and this is what you are looking for. In general, crons aren't for serveless functions. You can deploy the crons using queues for example or another third party service, check out [this link by vercel.](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-on-vercel)